# "dataLayer.push" or declare with "dataLayer =" for Analytics Ecommerce Tracking GTM

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

Which of these is more optimal?

I have a thank-you page, and I need to load all of my transaction sale info into this page to post it to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager.

Do I declare the dataLayer using the code below and post it before my GTM code?

```
dataLayer = [{
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '40008',
        'revenue': '90.00',
      },
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Clothes',
        'price': '9.00',
        'category': 'Shirt',
        'quantity': 10.00,
       }]
    }
  }
}];
```

or do I push the data into the dataLayer which is created automatically and post it after my GTM code?

```
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '40008',
        'revenue': '90.00',
      },
      'products': [{
        'name': 'Clothes',
        'price': '9.00',
        'category': 'Shirt',
        'quantity': 10.00,
       }]
    }
  }
});
```

What is the difference?  I will take the data from the dataLayer to Google with a "DOM Ready" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the dataLayer above the GTM tag for information that needs to be available immediately on page load. You use dataLayer.push for information that is added after the GTM tag.

I frankly do not think it makes that much difference in most use cases, but if you want to make sure data is available when the page loads you should declare a dataLayer. DOM ready means any push event within the source code has already happened, so it probably does not make a difference for you.

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between Dom Ready and Pageview?  Which one would I want to use if I am declaring the dataLayer before the page loads?

Comment: Page view (from the point of view of GTM) happens as soon as the browser hits the GTM code (usually GTM is integrated directly after the opening body tag), so it's the first opportunity to fire tags. DOM ready happens only after the complete structure if the page is loaded (the eponymous DOM), so that's a lot later in the load process.  Windows loaded (when all connected assets like images and css/script files have loaded) is last. If you declare the dataLayer above the GTM snippet then you would use a page view trigger (with page view as trigger type).